# How do I view Writer menu?

Tags: libreoffice, menu

This is a beginner's question, since I have not used Ubuntu for 3 years. In a fresh, updated 15.04 installation, in Writer, when I open an existing document I get the usual toolbars, but no menu. Since I need the menu to customize languages, can someone tell me how to view it?

Comment: It should be integrated into the top panel. Try moving the mouse pointer to the panel, while a Writer window is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Hover your mouse on the top of the window. It should appear.

Alternatively you can use `Alt + F10` shortcut.